# WinForms ListView and TreeView: strange performance issues

Tags: .net, winforms, performance, listview, treeview

When optimizing UI in our project I noticed really strange boost up in ListView and didn't understand where it comes from.

Simple adding 5000 elements to listView (View: List) - 3815 ms:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
         listView1.Items.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
```

With BeginUpdate() + EndUpdate() - 2317 ms:

```
listView1.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    listView1.Items.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
listView1.EndUpdate();
```

With Hide() + Show() - 163ms (NO MISTAKE, over 10 times faster):

```
listView1.Hide();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    listView1.Items.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
listView1.Show();
```

The style also changed. **Instead of 2 columns now I have 4.**

Why this way is so fast ?
Moreover, **why starting with hidden ListView (Visible: false), and showing it after population doesn't have the same performance boost ?**

TreeView is different. Simple adding 5000 nodes - 2130 ms:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    treeView1.Nodes.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
```

With Hide() + Show() - 1048 ms:

```
treeView1.Hide();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    treeView1.Nodes.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
treeView1.Show();
```

With BeginUpdate() + EndUpdate() - 291 ms:

```
treeView1.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    treeView1.Nodes.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
treeView1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Add your items to a list then call `AddRange(...)` also you should manually specify your columns rather than trusting the control to dynamically allocate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. When the control is hidden, it doesn't calculate the extents of the items (something like `Graphics.MeasureString` or its native equivalent) when they are added (which makes sense) and doesn't calculate it later, when the control is shown (which is probably a bug). For this reason you get 4 columns instead of 2. Notice that when you get 2 columns, items are not truncated, because this size calculation was performed. When you get 4 columns, the display is generally incorrect.

And why it doesn't make it with being invisible from the beginning? The reason is, because in this case the handle to the control is not created (underlying Win32 control is not created yet) until you call `Show` method or make anything what forces the handle to be created. And then, `Show` will create the handle for the first time, doing a lot of other code, including `OnHandleCreated` and somewhere at this point the code organizes the items and calculates their sizes.

You can check `IsHandleCreated` property is `false` until the first `Show` call, if the control was invisible from the beginning.

You can also create a handle explicitly, ie. by simply trying to read the `Handle` property (this forces the handle to be created), and then it behaves the same way - is fast, but the display is wrong:

```
IntPtr handle = listView1.Handle;
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    listView1.Items.Add((Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
listView1.Show();
```

If the handle was created earlier, the `OnHandleCreated` along with size calculation was invoked too, but at the time the list was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse if you are adding elements withou hide listview.. is drawing element after element and when you hide listview, than it will draw all elements at one time..

Comment: The real question is:
Why starting with hidden ListView (Visible: false), and showing it after population doesn't have the same performance boost ?

Why hide/show changes visible column count ?

Comment: the same answer.. because, if it is visible every element what you are adding is draw as single (it call after every new element  - draw).. but if you hide component and after show.. it draw it all at one( add all elements and after that it all draw on gui)..